# Isolation amplifier output problem

Tags: isolation

I am directly connect the Vin to isolation amplifier and observe the output, it clip at 2.5v at output,but we give 3.3v at highside,can anyone explain why this happen? here i am attaching the screenshots of my simulation.
[image: AMC1311 circuit]

[image: AMC1311 output waveform]

[image: amc1311 ratings]

Comment: can you link to a data sheet for AMC 1311 ? Does the data sheet say that the output can go up to the high side ?

Comment: Actually datasheet shows the differential output(VOUTP,VOUTN) is max VDD2+0.5, here i am attaching the screenshot of ratings of AMC1311 isolation amplifier.

Comment: Fig. 22, page 14 in **a** [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/amc1311.pdf) shows that only 2.5V is expected at the output ???

Answer (score 2):

According to the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/amc1311.pdf?ts=1599138277688&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FAMC1311), input voltage range is -0.1 to +2.0V for guaranteed linear operation.

For +2V in the outputs will typically be Vcm - 1V and Vcm + 1, where Vcm is 1.44V typically.

The Absolute Maximum ratings are not for operation, they indicate what externally applied voltage might immediately damage the chip.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum Vin is 2.5V, you're going up to 3V in your graph.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No problem with the model, the linear input voltage range is + - 2.5 V for 3.3 V VDD2.
The gain is 1.
[image: amc1]

[image: amc2]

[image: amc3]